# Use JavaScript to submit Ajax.BeginForm()

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, html

I'm typing this question away from my computer so I don't have the exact code, but the question might be straightforward enough without it.

When I have a submit button directly within an Ajax form and I click the button directly to submit, everything works fine, and as expected. The Ajax.Form POSTs back to the controller which returns a partial view that is rendered inside the current View that I have.

But what I need is for a button to be clicked in the Ajax.Form, and for a JavaScript function to run. The JavaScript function will do some vaildation which decides whether to submit the Ajax.Form or not.

I have tried putting 2 buttons in the Ajax.Form, a hidden submit button and a regular button. I used the onclick event of the regular button to call my JavaScript function which then called the click method of the hidden submit button. (I have also tried just submitting the Ajax.Form directly with document.forms[formname].submit() )

This sort of works.. But not correctly for some reason. The Ajax.Form POSTs back to the controller but when a partial view is returned from the controller, the partial view is the only thing rendered, and it is rendered as basic html with no css/bootstrap.

What is the difference between actually clicking the submit button and doing so programmatically?

How can Achieve what I am trying to do?

*Edit*

```
 @using (Ajax.BeginForm("GetInstructorInfo", "Incident", FormMethod.Post, new AjaxOptions { OnBegin = "lookupInstructor();", UpdateTargetId = "InstructorInfo" }, new { @class = "form-inline", role = "form", @id = "instructorInfoForm", @name = "instructorInfoForm" }))
{

//code in here

}
```

Edit 2 / 3:

```
<script>
    function lookupInstructor()
    {
        if ($('input[name="Instructors['+userInputInstructor+'].Username'+'"]').length > 0)   //Don't allow user to enter multiple instances of the same Instructor
        {
            document.getElementById("InstructorUsername").value = ''; //clear textbox value
            return false;
        }
        var userInputInstructor =  document.getElementById("InstructorUsername").value;
        $.ajax({
            url: '@Url.Content("~/Incident/LookUpUsername")',
            data: { userInput: userInputInstructor },
            success: function (result) {
                if (result.indexOf("not found") != -1){ //if not found

                    $("#InstructorNotFoundDisplay").show();
                    document.getElementById("InstructorUsername").value = ''; //clear textbox value

                    $('#InstructorInfo').empty();
                    return false;
                }
                else {
                    $("#InstructorNotFoundDisplay").hide();
                    return true;
                }
            }
        });
  }
</script>
```

Comment: If your using `Ajax.BeginForm()`, then you can use the [OnBegin](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.ajax.ajaxoptions.onbegin(v=vs.118).aspx#P:System.Web.Mvc.Ajax.AjaxOptions.OnBegin) ajax option to run a script before submitting (and cancel the submit is necessary)

Comment: @Stephen Muecke I did look at trying to use the OnBegin(), but it didn't work right when I implemented it. I didn't know you could cancel the submit, how would you do that?

Comment: You just `return false;` in the function. e.g. `function Validate() { if (isValid) { return true; } else { return false; }  }` and then in the ajax options `OnBegin = "return Validate();"` (but why people still use the obsolete `Ajax` methods instead of `$.ajax()` I'll never understand)

Comment: @StephenMuecke worked perfect! If you want to add this as an answer I will mark it as the answer. thank you very much. The reason I'm using whatever, ajax methods I have, is because i'm extremely new to web development, and I haven't had time to properly learn much at all. I'm just going off of previously written code I can reference for the time being. I can't wait to really sit down and learn this stuff.

Comment: @StephenMuecke Actually, It seems that the Ajax.BeginForm() still Posts back to the controller even if I specify { return false; } in the javascript function. I will add the header of the Ajax.BeginForm() to my OP. any reason the return false; isnt working?

Comment: It needs to be `OnBegin = "return lookupInstructor();"`

Comment: @StephenMuecke Okay that definitely helped, but I am still having a few issues with the {return true/false}. I have added the function code to my original OP. But I did test a simple function, and if I do a simple if/else and return true, and false respectively it works fine. So I am guessing it has to do with the nested functions maybe? In the code about I use a var functionResult variable to hold the return value, but I also tried returning true/false explicitly within then if/else of the $.ajax and that didnt work either. also, If I initialize functionResult as either true or false it works

Comment: You need to return the value of `functionResult` in the success callback (ajax is async so your actually returning `undefined` because the `return functionResult;` line is actually called before the ajax call has finished

Comment: @StephenMuecke like i said, I tried explicitly returning true or false instead of setting functionResult. I'll edit the OP edit with what I mean, and what seems like should work.

Comment: We are getting a bit of track from your original question. Your going to have to create separate functions to handle this. No time now, but edit my question a bit later (although I would recommend you abandon the `Ajax` methods and just use `jQuery.ajax()` - the `Ajax` functions have now been dropped from the latest version of MVC)

Comment: @StephenMuecke thank you very much for the help,  I dont know much about ajax in general, but If I can use $.ajax() to do what I am trying here, Id be open to it. what would the syntax look like? I'll look for your edit / answers tomorrow or whenever you get to it. thanks again!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [OnBegin()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.ajax.ajaxoptions.onbegin(v=vs.118).aspx#P:System.Web.Mvc.Ajax.AjaxOptions.OnBegin) ajax option to call a function that runs before the form is submitted (and `return false` if you want to cancel the submit). For example

```
function Validate() { 
    var isValid = // some logic
    if (isValid) { 
        return true; 
    } else { 
        return false;
    }
}
```

and then in the `Ajax.BeginForm()` options

```
OnBegin = "return Validate();"
```

**Edit**

Based on the edits to the question and the comments, you wanting to call an ajax function in the `OnBegin()` option which wont work because ajax is asynchronous. Instead, use `jQuery.ajax()` to submit you form rather than the `Ajax.BeginForm()` method (and save yourself the extra overhead of including `jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js`).

Change `Ajax.BeginForm()` to `Html.BeginForm()` and inside the form tags replace the submit button with `<button type="button" id="save">Save</button>`and handle its `.click()` event

```
var form = $('#instructorInfoForm');
var url = '@Url.Action("GetInstructorInfo", "Incident")';
var target = $('#InstructorInfo');

$('#save').click(function() {
  if ($('input[name="Instructors['+userInputInstructor+'].Username'+'"]').length > 0) {
    ....
    return; // exit the function
  }
  $.ajax({
    ....
    success: function (result) {
      if (result.indexOf("not found") != -1) {
        ....
      }
      else {
        $("#InstructorNotFoundDisplay").hide();
        // submit the form and update the DOM
        $.post(url, form.serialize(), function(data) {
          target.html(data);
        });
      }
    }
  });
});
```